# Prove that $\overline{AM}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{BM}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

All points are in the middle of this separating it into $3 $ equal parts prove that it is $\frac{1}{9}$ of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given the triangle draw AM and from that you get that ABD and AMC are similar then you get that BD is the middle point to AD is equal to GF and form that you get that am is pretty to bc